# Sprite Kit game not detecting two simultaneous touches

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit

I am developing a Sprite Kit game and need to react to touches on either the left or right side of the screen. I found this solution in another question:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self];

if (touchLocation.x < self.size.width / 2.0f) {
    touching = YES;
}

if (touchLocation.x > self.size.width / 2.0f) {
    [self drawRocket];
}
```

And,

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self];

if (touchLocation.x < self.size.width / 2.0f) {
    touching = NO;
}

if (touchLocation.x > self.size.width / 2.0f) {
    //do nothing
}
```

}

And I thought, brilliant. It works. Well, it seemed to, until I happened to touch both sides at the same time with separate fingers. It calls `drawRocket` but does not change the value of `touching` to `YES`. This problem has happened repeatedly and is replicable.

What to do?

EDIT:

I have tried:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self];



    if (touchLocation.x < self.size.width / 2.0f) {
        touching = YES;
    }

    if (touchLocation.x > self.size.width / 2.0f) {
        if (![rocketFlame parent]) {
            [self fireRocket];
        }
    }
}
```

}

and,

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self];


for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
    if (touchLocation.x < self.size.width / 2.0f) {
        touching = YES;
    }

    if (touchLocation.x > self.size.width / 2.0f) {
        if (![rocketFlame parent]) {
            [self fireRocket];
        }
    }
}
```

}

And I am still having the same problem.

Comment: you need to process all touches, not just [touches anyObject] .. ie enumerate over each touch: for (UITouch* touch in touches) { .. }

Comment: @LearnCocos2D please answer with a code example, I'm not sure which line to change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining a local variable that hides the variable used to loop over the touch events. See the comment in the code below.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {

        // The following statement is causing the issue. Delete it.
        //UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

        CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self];

        if (touchLocation.x < self.size.width / 2.0f) {
            touching = YES;
        }

        if (touchLocation.x > self.size.width / 2.0f) {
            if (![rocketFlame parent]) {
                [self fireRocket];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add the following line in the initilization method
 self.view.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;

```
for (UITouch *touch in touches) {

CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self];
if (touchLocation.x < self.size.width / 2.0f) {
    touching = YES;
}

if (touchLocation.x > self.size.width / 2.0f) {
    [self drawRocket];
}
}
```

Simulator Multi-Touch gestures using a mouse and keyboard

Comment: I tried this and I am still having the same problem.

Comment: please try touchLocation inside the Loop

Comment: see my edit, I have tried it in two places and it hasn't worked.